# colnames command produces error: attribute [13] must be the same length as the vector [12]

Tags: r

I am trying to rename columns in a data.frame. However, I keep getting the following error when I try to run the names, or colnames command in R

```
Error in names(HourlyTotal)["ZoneElectric"] <- "Meas.Elec" : 
  'names' attribute [13] must be the same length as the vector [12]
```

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
names(HourlyTotal)["ZoneElectric"] <- "Meas.Elec"
```

However, the code works fine if I use a column number instead of the column name.

```
names(HourlyTotal)[3] <- "Meas.Elec"
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? I appreciate any help, as this has me stumped for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `names(HourlyTotal)["ZoneElectric"]`, you are asking `R` to give you the element named `"ZoneElectric"` from the vector `names(HourlyTotal)`

However, **`names(HourlyTotal)` is an unnamed vector.**

What you want (I am guessing/assuming) is the element of `names(HourlyTotal)` whose ***value*** is `"ZoneElectric"`.   If you happen to know in which position in the vector it occurs, then you can use numeric indexing, as you have discovered (ie, `names(HourlyTotal)[3]`).  However, a more robust solution is to filter for that specific value:

#### Therefore, use:

```
names(HourlyTotal)[names(HourlyTotal) == "ZoneElectric"] <- ... 

# Instead of 
#    names(HourlyTotal)["ZoneElectric"] <- ...
```

Or you can use `setnames` from the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
setnames(HourlyTotal, old="ZoneElectric", new="NewName")
```

Comment: That's great, this works perfect, and is far more robust than using the numeric index for the column (which may change). I really appreciate all your comments on this. I've been running into roadblocks with a few things on R over the last few days, but I think it's starting to make sense now.

Comment: Glad to hear.  Google `"The R Inferno"` -- a very handy (free?) book

Answer (score 0):

`names(HourlyTotal)["ZoneElectric"]` should return `NA`. The result of `names(HourlyTotal)` is a vector which you can subset by element number.

Why don't you use something like this? - 
`setnames(dt,"ZoneElectric","Meas.Elec")`

Comment: I don't see anything in the question about data tables. Probably you meant `setNames` which has a slightly different syntax.

Comment: @Joran, while you are right in your observation re: not related to data.table.  `setnames` **does** work on data.frames

Comment: I agree, but offering up a solution using a function from a package not mentioned in the question would suggest that _you_ should mention needing to load that package, no?

Comment: I don't understand. Like @RicardoSaporta says, setnames works on a `data.frame` as well. Where's `data.table` coming in?

Comment: @Codoremifa, What Joran is saying (and I completely agree) is that if you are suggesting a solution that involves using a function specific to a package, you should be explicit about that